# multiple checkboxes in listview in compactframework

Tags: compact-framework

in my mobile 6.5 application i have one check box shown in start of my listview  using this code

ListBatch.Columns.Add(" ", 30, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] {String.Empty,"2","3"});

lvi.Checked = false;

but how can i have two checkboxes????

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to [custom draw the ListView](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html).  You might also use a DataGrid and [custom format it](http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/DataGrid_extensions_for_the_Compact_Framework).